# How can i achieve module subfolders where i can have multiple 'module' folders in a folder inside modules called api? On Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, module

How can i achieve module subfolders, where i can have multiple 'module' folders in a folder inside modules called api.

- application/modules/api/module1/...
- application/modules/api/module2/...
- application/modules/api/module3/...
- application/modules/module1/...

My purpose is to create a restful api but have all those new modules under a subdirectory.

Another catch here, is that modules outside of the app may have the same name as the ones outside. So My class naming would be like..

Api_Module1_...
Api_Module2_...
Api_Module3_...
Module1...

I cant seem to actually make this work so far...

Answer (score 0):

open your application.ini and do

```
;for normal modules
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory[] = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"   

;for modules inside api
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules/api"
```

and then in your bootstrap do

```
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->removeControllerDirectory('api');
```

this will not do Api_Module1 for that to work you need to do many other thing such as create your own standard router.

Comment: and how would i access these modules?
this => 'http://www.example.com/api/module1'
Doesnt work!
And even so, i cant create routes with module 'api_module', its not accesible! The routing is the problem actually.

Comment: yes that will not work since there is no module name api , all are normal modules only diff is some are inside api folders . You will have to work it on autloaders and routers to achieve your last requirement.

Comment: Well thats my question? how could i work this on? what are the steps to make it happen?

Comment: I think the modules are loading but i cant actually use them in routing because I dont know the name of each of them. Also, it would be even more perfect if this could happen automatically and every module in that folder could be routed automatically.